# Which parts of Shopify Dev should I look at to solve this problem

Tags: api, shopify

I am an experienced developer but never done anything in Shopify. I’ve seen apps, APIs iframes and more in the shopify doc and would like an overview from someone of how they would tackle this request please?

We are after a vehicle finder that can be used on multiple sites/store fronts, we currently have 14 sites.

The vehicle finder app we are currently using is too basic, not offering an after-search filtering system
What I mean by this is I need a vehicle finder that allows you to do the normal Honda > Civic > 2.0 > 2004 but then once the products have come up to then be able to say, Front or rear or even compounds etc.

I want something we can update in house whenever we want, is customisable to fit into the site as nice as possible. It also
needs to be able to be on different sites, so the data must be pulled from inventory.

Comment: I don't get why Shopify? Are the car inside a Shopify as products? I think to implement a complex logic like you described, you will need a separate database to run the queries as you like them. Shopify Products API (Rest or Graphql) will quickly fall short of your needs. And that's what most Filter apps do. They save the products in their own database and just expose their API.

Comment: The site is already on Shopify… they want it extending to add this functionality

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an app (https://shopify.dev) that creates some REST endpoint to set filters and get the result, that will be called through ajax.

Under the hood you could just using the Shopify API (rest or graphql) or you could duplicate the database of products and build your own logic in the DB queries.

This really depends on the requirements (number of cars, etc), but I'm pretty sure you will make few requests for a single user interaction if you stick with Shopify API.

If you want to "duplicate" the db you will need to regsiter a webhook to update it everytime a product is added or updated.

So the first approach is easier to start but is going to cost you in the long period, the first is a bit tricky to set up but it will be under your complete control.